# Trouble with printing my output from tkinter 3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I wrote this code to help me with my geometry homework. It's really simple right now. The code right now looks like this:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.grid()

a=Label(root,text = "X")
a.grid(row=1, column=1)
x=Entry(root)
x.grid(row=1, column=2)
y=Entry(root)
y.grid(row=3, column=2)
b=Label(root,text="Y")
b.grid(row=3, column=1)
x3=Entry(root)
x3.grid(row=1, column=5)
c=Label(root,text = "x3")
c.grid(row=1, column=4)
y3=Entry(root)
y3.grid(row=3,column=5)
d=Label(root,text = "y3")
d.grid(row=3, column=4)
label=Label(root).grid(row=2,column=9,columnspan=3)
k=Label(root,text ="M(Slope)")
k.grid(row=1,column=6)
l=Entry(root).grid(row=2,column=6)





def midpoint():
    e=((float(x.get())+(float(x3.get())))/2.0)
    f=((float(y.get())+(float(y3.get())))/2.0)
    print ("Midpoint = (",e,",",f,")")

def slope():
    h=((float(y3.get())-(float(y.get()))))
    i=((float(x3.get())-(float(x.get()))))
    print ('Slope = ',h,'/',i,'')

g=Button(root, text="Midpoint", command=midpoint).grid(row=7,column=1)
j=Button(root,text="slope", command=slope).grid(row=7,column=2)
mainloop()
```

The problem is when I click the midpoint button, i get this:

```
Midpoint = (
```

Then when i hit it again I get this:

```
Midpoint = ( 2.0 , 3.0 )
Midpoint = (
```

I'm not quite sure why that happens. The second thing i wanted to do was rename the variables, so i made a code like this just to make it a little easier:

```
x1=(float(x.get())
y1=(float(y.get())
x2=(float(x3.get())
y2=(float(y3.get())
```

However it gives me a syntax error and i do not know why. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The midpoint is successfully printing on my machine. Are you sure you're running your most up-to-date code? And that the code you pasted here is the most up-to-date code?

Comment: As for the syntax error, there's nothing wrong with the four lines you posted. Sometimes the error misreports the line number that the problem is occurring on. Check the line just above that section. In particular, check that all of your parentheses match up. If you have something like `print("Now populating x1, y1, x2, and y2..."`, the interpreter won't notice that anything's wrong until it reads the next line.

Comment: I'm such an idiot, i forgot to add my last parentheses. Now however it is giving me an error saying this: builtins.ValueError: could not convert string to float:. Do you know what's wrong??? @Kevin

Comment: That usually happens when the return value of `get` is a string that can't be converted to a number, such as "hello" or "3,14", or "". Are you doing those assignments in the `midpoint` or `slope` functions? If not, they're probably executing instantly, long before the user can enter any values into the text boxes. So it will try to turn the empty string into a float, and crash.

Comment: Yo it works now!!! I just moved them to the definitions. Thanks!!!